# How to create a Django with existing directories, files and etc.?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to startproject with

```
django-admin startproject <project_name>
```

but it either makes more files that already exists (like manage.py, and other configurations files) or gives an error - CommandError: ~/Dev/r4c/R4C/manage.py already exists. Overlaying a project into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files.

My project structure:

```
r4c/
└── R4C/
    ├── R4C/
    │   └── settings.py
        └── ... (other configuration files)
    ├── customers/
    │   └── views.py
        └── ... (other customer-related files)
    ├── orders/
    │   └── views.py
        └── ... (other customer-related files)
    └── robots/
        └── views.py
        └── ... (other customer-related files)
    ├── R4C_README.md
    ├── R4C_manage.py
    └── R4C_tasks.md
```

I just need to start the project and apps with already existing directories and files

I tried to startproject command but cant get and idea of not just starting project from the beginning, just work with existing ffiles and directories.

Comment: Try starting a Django app instead of a Django project.

Comment: If you already have the project then you don't need to create it again, so what are you trying to do?

Comment: You need `manage.py startapp <appname>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already django structure and configuration, you don't need to use `django-admin startproject` again.

If you want to make sure that your directories like customers, orders, and robots are Django apps, you can follow these steps:

- First, make sure each of these directories has an **init**.py file (even if it's empty) so that Python recognizes them as modules.
- Then, in each directory, create or ensure there's a models.py file. This file is essential for Django to recognize the directory as an app.
- Finally, in your main project's settings.py, add these apps to the INSTALLED_APPS list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'customers',
    'orders',
    'robots',
    ...
]
```

As long as you maintain the correct structure and contents required by Django in your directories and files, you don't need to use the startproject or startapp commands. They are convenience commands provided by Django to help set up the initial structure, but once that structure exists (as in your case), you can proceed with the development directly.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the project, there is no need to run the command for the project again. Now you need to build apps, i.e., write models and views for your app.You can use following cmd for creating app

```
python manage.py startapp myapp
```